# Android 4.0.3 OpengL ES 2.0 issue

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, live-wallpaper

i develop live wallpapers using Opengl ES 2.0 engine. 
My wallapapers run smooth on 2.x Android Devices , but in 4.03 i see some strange things.
1st seconds (maybe a minute max) lwp runs smooth , but after that starts dropping frames especially when objects passing near camera allmost crashes. But no error on eclipse Log.
I watched Eclipse log from the begining of loading the lwp to the point of dropping frames.
I ve seen that on My LG optimus 2X , and my Samsung Galaxy S2. 
Any Idea what to check , or what is going on??

UPDATE i just noticed that changing render mode from dirty to continuously fixed the problem , but until screen orientation changes , or goes of and on. after that renderer freaks out.

---

UPDATE

I noticed something weird

in preview mode , everything goes fine when i change orientation , and turn off and on screen , because glWallpaperService.glEngine.onsurfacedestroyed is triggered!
in normal mode , this does'nt happen!
even if i turn of the screen , the only void that triggers is onsurfaceChanged!
but GLThread destroyes the surface both modes.

Whats the difference between normal and preview mode? and why preview mode triggers onsurfacedestroyed on every change?

Comment: just give your code to provide a better solution..